# How can I create a realistic 3D texture in Photoshop or Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, 3d, texture

Does anyone know how I can create this kind of texture in Photoshop or Illustrator ?

[image: Geometric 3D Pattern]

**I've tried** the Bevel & Emboss filters in Photoshop (and drop shadow, inner shadow etc.) and also the 3D Extrusion in Illustrator, but I can't manage to get something as realistic.

**I've also tried** in 3DS Max but I can't get something clean...

Does anyone know if there is a simple way to import a texture like [this one](http://www.sandbes.com/store/images/watermarked/1/detailed/2/sp_152_01.gif) for example, keep the black shapes and extrude them so that they look as good as the first picture?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your attempts so we can see where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Import your image into Photoshop. Go to the Channels tab and CTRL click on the thumbnail next to the word Index.

[image]

Go to Image > Mode > RGB Color. Press CTRL+Shift+I to invert your selection to select the black droplets. Hit CTRL+C then CTRL+V to copy the droplets to a new layer.

[image]

Create a layer with a white fill between your current layers. You can turn off or delete the Original layer.

[image]

With the top layer selected, invert the colors (CTRL+I) to make them off-white. Go to Layer > Matting > Defringe to remove the black fringe around the droplets.

[image]

Apply a layer style and choose your desired settings.

[image]

Create a new layer at the top of the stack and fill it with white.

[image]

Go to Filter > Render > Lighting Effects and apply a Spot Light and position and adjust as you see fit.

[image]

Change the top layer to Multiply mode (or any other that you'd like).

[image]

You can now reorder the layers to achieve your desired effect...

[image]

Or add similar lighting effects to the cut outs (droplets) layer...

[image]

Keep in mind that there are variables at many of the later steps here and you should use your keen eye to best determine the overall effect you're after.